# Training set for automatic transcription of singing

Tags: voice, software, midi, transcription

I'm making an automatic music transcription system for singing so that you can convert your voice to midi. To train the system, I need WAVs of singing that are perfectly synched to midi files.

Does anyone have any suggestions of the best way to get this training set?

One thought was to take a midi file and then use it to produce vocalese. However, I don't know where I might find good samples. This obviously isn't as good as true singing, but could at least serve as a simple baseline.

Another option would be to find some pre-recorded monophonic singing for which midi is available and then using dynamic time warping to sync them. Again, I would need to find a source for this.

Comment: Sorry, we don't talk about equipment or software recommendations here.

Comment: May I suggest editing your question to be a little less equipment-recommendationy? Perhaps just ask for ways to obtain a training data set? Otherwise your question may be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I reworded it so that it was asking for how I might obtain a training set. Is this not less equipment recommendationy enough?

Comment: @Luke I thought so, but apparently others disagreed. I've asked about it in chat to see if it can be clarified.

Comment: @Luke It appears that it was closed because it asks for off-site resources. I'd recommend heading to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) and seeing if you can clarify this understanding.

Comment: Why not take vocal recordings and convert them to midi and then use those for training?

Comment: @ToddWilcox that would definitely produce the best training data. It would also be extremely arduous to do by hand. Unless you know of some easier way.

Comment: By using any one of several widely available music-to-midi conversion software packages?